# Create a List of Map by splitting a string

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap

I have a string whose value can be `Insert`, `Insert&Update` or `Update`. Now based on this value, i have to create a `Map` as below.

Case 1 : When `myString="Insert"`, i need output like this

```
"Database": [
                {
                    "Action": "Insert"
                }
            ]
```

Case 2 : When `myString="Insert&Update"`, i need output like this

```
"Database": [
                {
                    "Action": "Insert"
                },
                {
                    "Action": "Update"
                }
            ]
```

Case 1 : When `myString="Update"`, i need output like this

```
"Database": [
                {
                    "Action": "Update"
                }
            ]
```

I'm new to java and based on my knowledge what i'm doing currently is manually checking the condition and creating the list manually(something like below). Is there any way that I can split `myString` and automatically create this list?

```
Map<String, String> database = new HashMap<String, String>();
List<Map<String, String>> subList = new ArrayList<>();              
if(myString.equals("Insert")){              
    database.put("Action", "Insert");
    subList.add(database);
} else if(myString.equals("Insert&Update")){
    database.put("Action", "Insert");
    subList.add(database);
    database = new HashMap<String, String>();
    database.put("Action", "Update");
    subList.add(database);
} else {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `myString.split("&")` to get an array of actions. Then you can iterate over it and generate all actions:

```java
List<Map<String, String>> actions = new LinkedList<>();
String[] strings = myString.split("&");
for (String s : strings) {
  actions.add(action(s));
}
```

using this helper function to generate the action dictionaries:

```java
Map<String, String> action(String action) {
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("Action", action);
  return map;
}
```

Just bear in mind that if somebody submits `myString=Messing&With&You` this code isn't validating the input unlike your original code. So you could wrap your `put` in an `if`:

```java
if (s.equals("Insert") || s.equals("Update")) {
  actions.add(action(s));
}
```

You might also want to throw an exception if your input is invalid:

```java
if (actions.size() != strings.length) {
  throw new Exception("Inputs invalid");
}
```

Putting everything together:

```java
Map<String, String> action(String action) {
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("Action", action);
  return map;
}

void handle(String myString) {
  List<Map<String, String>> actions = new LinkedList<>();
  String[] strings = myString.split("&");
  for (String s : strings) {
    if (s.equals("Insert") || s.equals("Update")) {
      actions.add(action(s));
    }
  }
  if (actions.size() != strings.length) {
    throw new Exception("Inputs invalid");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Stop working harder and start working smarter**

Do this:

1. Analyze the requirements.
   Upon analysis,
   this becomes clear: you are implementing a variation of FizzBuzz.
2. Implement an appropriate solution.

Google search for "FizzBuzz" if you don't recognize the reference.

Here is the solution to your problem:

1. Receive a string as input.
2. If the input contains the word "Insert",
   add an insert entry to the output map.
3. If the input contains the word "Update",
   add an update entry to the output map.
4. Return the output map.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your string has only one of the possible three values (otherwise add a filter), you can do it quite easily as follows

```
String myString = ... ;
    
List<Map<String, String>> subList = Arrays.stream(myString.split("&"))
                                          .map(str -> Collections.singletonMap("Action", str))
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```